# To kill batch process which running in backend

Tags: windows, vb.net, batch-file

Developing use VB recently, just like jump from hole to another....

Here is my issue. I am using Visual Basic, Start button to click -> run batch file in the back end, user can not see it, and also there is one button 'Abort', when it`s clicked, the process (batch file running in back end) should be killed.

However, it does not.

```
Dim pathtobatfile As String
    pathtobatfile = mainPath & "TEMP\extract.bat"
    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo(pathtobatfile)
    psi.RedirectStandardError = True
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    psi.CreateNoWindow = True
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.hidden

    psi.UseShellExecute = False
    process= process.Start(psi)
```

Above set up start the process

```
    process.CloseMainWindow() 
    process.Kill()
    process.Close()
```

All did not work, but if set 'psi.CreateNoWindow = false'
and use  process.CloseMainWindow() to close the batch file window, it will stop.
but I don`t want the CMD window pop-up to users...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set unnecessary things to hide the Window, try this:

Declare the process outside the procedure:

```
Private p As New Process With {.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo With { _
           .FileName = string.empty, _
           .RedirectStandardError = True, _
           .RedirectStandardOutput = True, _
           .CreateNoWindow = True, _
           .UseShellExecute = False _
}}
```

Then...:

```
Private Sub StartProcess()
    p.Filename = mainPath & "TEMP\extract.bat"
    p.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub KillProcess()
    If Not p.HasExited() Then
        p.Kill()
    End If
End Sub
```